# Problem mounting the file

Tags: downloads

I have tried to download Ubuntu desktop two times now using google chrome and every time I try to open the file up it says sorry there is a problem mounting the file. I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: I guess you mean desktop distribution iso. Which softwre you use to open it?

Comment: try the command and check whether the machine_config has mounted then use df to list all the mounted paths.

Comment: I'm going to guess that GregIrvin is not running linux currently, sounds more like trying to create a bootable dvd/usb problem - i.e. what to do with the iso

Comment: just download the file with `wget` as `wget url`

Comment: Consider adding more detail, what OS, how are you trying to mount or what do you actually try to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're on windows, and having trouble with what to do with the Ubuntu iso. Options include

- [Creating a bootable cd/dvd](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)
- Creating a bootable usb ([Ubuntu help page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or  [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) on http://www.pendrivelinux.com/
- Using a virtual machine (VM) program like VirtualBox to boot the iso & run it in a VM

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Chrome` tries to execure the default action, so to download only the file, just right click on a link, then select `save link as`...

or the variant is to copy link to a clipboard, and then open a terminal, type `wget`, and press `Shift`+`Insert` to insert the link into a command line, so it be:

```
wget url
```

Then press `Enter`.